# pip version in Ubuntu is different

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I meet a issue about pip version in Ubuntu  is different as the following:

This is my virtual machine - Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-15-generic x86_64)

[image]

The pip version is 6.0.8 (6.X.X):

[image]

Another virtual machine is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. It's downloaded form [Ubuntu  desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

The pip version is 1.5.4 (1.X.X):

[image]

They are in same operation system. Why are they different?

Comment: What do you mean? One is Ubuntu 12 and t he other is Ubuntu 14. Of course they will be different.

Comment: @dan-klasson May you post on answer to explain it? Sorry, I don't understand Ubuntu clearly.

Comment: Each version of Ubuntu generally comes with packages with different versions. But what I don't understand is why a later version of Ubuntu would have an older version.

Comment: @dan-klasson If you find solution, please let me know. Thx.

Comment: You want Ubuntu 14 to have the latest version of pip?

Comment: @dan-klasson No. I just need a explanation about the difference. Let me can explain other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, the version seems right:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python/python-pip

For Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, I am not sure why the version shows as `6.1.1`, when it should be:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/python-pip

I suspect somebody updated pip on the second machine at some point.

Comment: It' me when I updated the second machine. It's good resource to check pip why it's installed in different version Ubuntu will be with different versions. I upvote for you.

Comment: Good to know that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Each version of Ubuntu generally comes with packages with different versions. Applications release new and improved versions of their software, and it's only natural for Ubuntu to include a more recent stable version of it.

Comment: It's passable explanation but I upvote for your effort.